# Get the <span> value for each webpage with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list of websites that I want to loop through and extract the Genres of the films. They all come from boxofficemojo.

An example link is the following: https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl3829564929/

In the inspect, the structure of the page for the section that I want to extract is like this:

```
<div class = "a-section a-spacing-none">
   <span>Genres</span>
 </div>
  <span>
  Action Adventure Thriller
 </span>
```

When I run the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl3829564929/")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[7]/span[2]") 
my_element.text
```

I get the following results:

```
'Action Adventure Thriller'
```

which is the desirable result for this particular movie. However,when I go to other movies, the xpath is different and I cannot access it automatically.

The ideal solution would be to loop through the websites and extract the genres of the films irrespective of the xpath that the  Genres has in each individual film page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each relevant website you visit, if the label *`Genre`* is followed by the genre name within a `<span>` tag, to extract the text you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl3829564929/")
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Genres']//following::span[1]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl3829564929/")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Genres']//following::span[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Action Adventure Thriller
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none' and contains(.,'Genres')]/span[2]") 
my_element.text
```

Search for a more unique xpath that fits your perimeters.